# magento 2 rest api add to cart with custom options type file jpg

Tags: magento2

I am trying using rest API to add a product to cart with custom options type file jpg, but when I sent the request I got an error "message": "Please specify product's required option(s).",a part of code my request

```
"customOptions": [
                    {
                      "optionId": "2",
                      "optionValue": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg...",
                      "extensionAttributes": {
                        "fileInfo": {
                          "base64EncodedData": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAo....",
                          "type": "image/jpeg",
                          "name": "image.jpeg"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
```

and I also tried with

```
"customOptions": [
                    {
                      "optionId": "2",
                      "optionValue": "image.jpeg",
                      "extensionAttributes": {
                        "fileInfo": {
                          "base64EncodedData": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA....",
                          "type": "image/jpeg",
                          "name": "image.jpeg"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use your second option and remove ".jpeg" from `optionValue`.

Based on this answer this could be your problem: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217547/magento-2-rest-api-add-product-to-cart-with-custom-option-type-file